# I'm trying to filter my data with Dplyr Code but mutate, filter and select are't working

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr

I'm working with an archaeological data set, and attempting to create a new variable called completeness_MNE. It would first filter out my data by getting rid of rows that are either missing a all zones (missing any of several is fine, but not all) and/or have a completeness of less than 50%.  Then with the rest it would total my specimens by species, element and side.

Error: it's not defining pComplete or Element_Side

#out of the subsetted data set (of bones with a completeness of = 50 or greater, give me the maximum number of elements per side)

```
completeness_MNE <- data %>% 
  filter(is.na(`Zone 1`) & is.na(`Zone 2`) & is.na(`Zone 3`) & is.na(`Zone 4`) & is.na(`Zone 5`) & is.na(`Zone 6`) & is.na(`Zone 7`) & is.na(`Zone 8`) & is.na(`Zone 9`)) %>% #added this line
  mutate(pComplete = case_when(PERCENT < 50 ~ "Incomplete",
                               PERCENT >= 50 ~ "Complete")) %>%
  filter(pComplete == "Complete") %>%
  filter(SIDE %in% c("axial", "both", "left", "right")) %>%
  mutate(Element_Side = paste(ELEMENT, SIDE)) %>%
  group_by(`Scientific Name`, pComplete, ELEMENT) %>%
  count(Element_Side) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(`Scientific Name`, Element_Side, MNE = n)
```

data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dORbnAcEKKBPoVc486jImqUq-lV9-G_k/view?usp=sharing): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dORbnAcEKKBPoVc486jImqUq-lV9-G_k/view?usp=sharing

I get the error: Error in select(., `Scientific Name`, Element_Side, MNE = n) :
unused arguments (`Scientific Name`, Element_Side, MNE = n)

head(data)

## A tibble: 6 x 55

BONEID FULLID CONTEXTNO sitecode `Unit Number` `Recovery Locat…` Recovery Metho… RECOVERY context SAMPLENO Taxa  `Size Class` SPECIES
                                                                 
1      1 BS001… BS001-NA  BS001    NA            Surface          Hand Collection  hc       NA      1        Mamm… Class IV     cow
2      2 BS001… BS001-NA  BS001    NA            Surface          Hand Collection  hc       NA      1        Mamm… Class IV     cow
3      3 BS001… BS001-NA  BS001    NA            Surface          Hand Collection  hc       NA      1        Mamm… Class III    pig?
4      4 BS001… BS001-NA  BS001    NA            Surface          Hand Collection  hc       NA      1        Mamm… Class IV     cow
5      5 BS001… BS001-NA  BS001    NA            Surface          Hand Collection  hc       NA      1        Mamm… Class IV     cow
6      6 BS001… BS001-NA  BS001    NA            Surface          Hand Collection  hc       NA      1        Mamm… Class IV     cow

## … with 42 more variables: `Common Name` , `Scientific Name` , `Element code` , ELEMENT , COUNT ,

## WEIGHT , `Percent Complete` , PERCENT , Condition , SIDE , `Zones Total` , PROXFUS ,

## DISTFUS , AGE , MODIFICATIONS , TEXTURE , ARTICULATION , `Fire Alteration` , Extent ,

## Butchery , `Butchery Type` , BUTCHTYPE , `Butchery Location` , `Butchery Description` , NOTES ,

## `Zone 1` , `Zone 2` , `Zone 3` , `Zone 4` , `Zone 5` , `Zone 6` , `Zone 7` , `Zone 8` ,

## `Zone 9` , A , B , C , D , E , F , G , H

> 

Comment: Could you please clarify for me again the problem? Your code works.

Comment: When I run it, it doesn't create Element_Side or pComplete, so that it ends in the error: Error in select(., `Scientific Name`, Element_Side, MNE = n) : 
  unused arguments (`Scientific Name`, Element_Side, MNE = n)

Comment: Can you please put a sample of dataset here? Don't have access to google drive at work

Comment: Also, sometimes this error happens because of `select` get masked by other libraries. try running `select <- dplyr::select` and try again

Comment: This is my first question on stack exchange so I'm stil learning how to best post my question and add data. I've tried editing it to include head(data) above

Comment: Adding select <- dplyr::select fixed it!! Thank you!!!